# Choosing a nonlinear model: GAM?

Tags: r, model, nonlinear

I have the response variable that is an abundance matrix Y. for example, I have four columns with

- species 1
- species 2
- species 3
- and species 4

  abundances at each location (each location is separate row).

I have a matrix X which include a set of environmental parameters (e.g. Temperature and salinity).

I need to predict what will be my abundance matrix $Y_i$ (i.e. abundance of

- Species1=...,
- species 2=...,
- species 3=...,
- and species 4=...)

at a given set of environmental conditions ( for example T=20, S=35)

I saw a method that was using multivariate multiple regression approach:

```
model=lm(cbind(A,B) ~ c+d+e+f+g)
```

However, in my model, the relationship is not linear. so I was wondering whether you can suggest some other method.

I was thinking of doing the following steps:

1. Train a model to give a probability of occurrence of any combination of abundance matrix Y in a given set of environmental conditions
2. Use this model to predict what abundance matrix will look like for a new set of env conditions

I am trying it on on another dataset :

```
dataset(airquality)
fmla= cbind(Day, Month)~Ozone + Wind + Temp
```

I am not sure whether GAM model will be appropriate for this.

Comment: It could definitely be appropriate! But we need to see your data to answer. Can you share them?

Comment: I agree with DeltaIV, there is no reason to think a GAM would be inappropriate. You might wish to consider a multivariate normal additive model.

Comment: Ps you can also share just a random sample, if you're concerned about the amount of data (but I I'm sure it's nothing a cloud-based system can't handle). Or you can share some fake data, reasonably which are similar to your real data, if you're concerned about publicly sharing data. But to answer we need to have a look at something.

Comment: thanks everyone for your replies. Unfortunately, I am still preparing my data- so I don't have it yet ( I am working with file that are 4Gb, so it takes ages do anything on them, so now I am in process of compiling all the data together).  i am now trying to test the code on teh following data set: `dataset(airquality)`. i am just not familiar with how to construct the model cause I never had to program the multiple response variable in one model.
`fmla= cbind(Day, Month)~Ozone + Wind + Temp`

Comment: I think you have the model the wrong way round don't you: you want `cbind(Ozone, Wind, Temp) ~ s(Day) + s(Month)` say. (I can't see why you'd want to predict the day or Month from the air quality measurements.

Comment: It is a random dataset I chose to try whether my code works as I can't yet  use my real data. I thought that the formula is y~x1 + x2+ ... but based on your example `cbind(Ozone, Wind, Temp) ~ s(Day) + s(Week)` it seems reverse, I thought that part that is in cbind corresponds to response variable

Comment: It does - my point was the way you have it, you appear to be wanting to predict the environment from the species. In the `airquality` example, Ozone and Temp would be the response variables, right? If not, Why would you want to predict a date?

Comment: oh, i see what you mean, thanks so much for your clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make some assumptions about the nature of the response, but one option is to fit a multivariate normal model, which is possible for example in **mgcv**.

Using the `airquality` dataset mentioned in the question, we might have

```
data(airquality)
aq <- transform(airquality,
                date = as.Date(paste('1973', Month, Day, sep = '-')))
aq <- transform(aq, DoY = as.numeric(format(date, '%j')))
```

and we might assume (probably naively) that Ozone`and`Temp` are multivariate normal. In which case we can fit the model using

```
m <- gam(list(Ozone ~ s(DoY),
              Temp  ~ s(DoY)),
         data = aq, family = mvn(d=2))
```

where we specify the linear predictors for the two, in this instance, response variables. I chose to model them as smooth functions of the day of year and implicit in this model is the estimation of a covariance matrix.

```
> summary(m)

Family: Multivariate normal 
Link function: 

Formula:
Ozone ~ s(DoY)
Temp ~ s(DoY)

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    42.1293     2.6470   15.92   <2e-16 ***
(Intercept).1  77.8707     0.5704  136.53   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(DoY)   3.546  4.385  34.42 1.37e-06 ***
s.1(DoY) 5.711  6.832 149.04  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Deviance explained = 41.9%
-REML =  708.4  Scale est. = 1         n = 116
```

That covariance matrix can be extracted via

```
solve(crossprod(m$family$data$R))
```

which results in

```
> solve(crossprod(m$family$data$R))
         [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 812.7657 104.67443
[2,] 104.6744  37.73835
```

or as a correlation matrix

```
> cov2cor(solve(crossprod(m$family$data$R)))
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5976769
[2,] 0.5976769 1.0000000
```

If your response is a count or similar abundance measure, you'll need to transform them if you are going to try the multivariate normal as abundances tend to be skewed and exhibit heterogeneous variance.

Alternatively, if the response matrix $Y$ contains counts from a total, you might use the multinomial response model. This can be done in **mgcv** also via the `multinom` family.

There's nothing stopping you from using `ns()` or `bs()` terms in the linear model example you had found — you just won't have smoothness selection so you'll need to tune the degrees of freedom/wiggliness of the fitted smooths yourself. `bs()` and `ns()` are in the **splines** package, which comes with R.

Related models could be estimated using a multivariate adaptive regression spline approach, with an R implementation in the **earth** package, which can now fit these models as GLMs — which might be appropriate given the nature of your response data (counts?)

Alternatively, joint species distribution models (JSDMs) are currently quite popular in ecology and in active development. The idea often involves stacking the columns of your matrix $Y$ and then adding factor variables for `site` and `species` which are then introduced into the model via random effects for `site:species` or latent factor variables.

A recent JSDM overview can be found in Warton et al (2015).

Warton DI, Blanchet FG, O’Hara RB et al. So Many Variables: Joint Modeling in Community Ecology. Trends in ecology & evolution [Internet] 2015;Available from: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tree.2015.09.007

Comment: thank you so much for this detailed answer. How does it change if I cant combine together my response variables? For example, I have Abundance of species 1 and 2 as my response and my independent variables are Temperature, salinity, and depth?

Comment: You can combine the responses. Abundances of spp1 and spp2 would be in the response side of the model, and the covariates (Temperature etc) would be on the right hand side of `~` --- in the `gam()` model I show at least. You'll need to look at the implementation details however for **earth** if you want to try that. For `lm`, you use `cbind()` on the species to form a matrix - I'm not sure if that linear model is estimating the covariances between responses (species). For JSDMs I suggest you read that paper for directions on how to proceed.

Comment: What you need to decide is how to model the species. The multivariate normal treats them as is correlated Gaussian random variables and abundances tend not to be Gaussian (they can't be negative for example) so you might consider log transforming the abundances. The multinomial model would consider your response as counts from a total - like you count 100 individuals and assign each individual to one of the species - then you have a model that is similar to a logit regression but for more than 2 classes/species. You should give some more info on the actual nature of your species abundances.

Comment: thanks so much for the directions! i already downloaded a paper for further reading. yes I will definitely log transform the abundance values and also add 1 (eg log(abund)+1). my abundances are usually reported either counts per m^2 or per m^3

Comment: I think you mean to use the transformation `log(abund + 1)`, right?

Comment: Yes, correct.  I typed it wrong